# How do I mount a single file in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a project that need to mount a single directory into the docker container, and I mount it in a similar way

```
agent:
    image: agent:latest
    container_name: agent
    volumes:
      - $PWD/status.txt:/status.txt
```

`Is A Directory` error occurs when I modify status.txt in `open` mode.

```
with open('status.txt','a') as f:
    ...
    ...
```

docker-compose seems to **recognize files as directories**.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it?

Comment: You `docker-compose.yml` works just fine for me. If you get a directory instead of a file, that means that from Docker's perspective the source file didn't exist. Can you tell us more about your environment? Are you running Docker under Linux? MacOS? Windows?

Comment: @larsks I run docker under linux with Ubuntu

Comment: Don't use `$PWD` in the volume mapping and instead use `./status.txt:/status.txt`! `./status.txt` will always refer to the file `status.txt` right next to the `docker-compose.yml` while using `$PWD` might yield unexpected results when you run `docker-compose` form another directory then the one containing the `docker-compose.yml`.

Answer (score 0):

I can mount files just fine using the same syntax, although I use a relative path, e.g.:

```
volumes:
 - ./sourcedir/file.txt:/target/dir/mountedfile.txt
```

Where `mountedfile.txt` is essentially `file.txt`. There must be something else in your environment causing this issue. To troubleshoot, there are a couple of things you could do, including:

1. Get a shell into the container and run `stat` on the target file, e.g. `stat mountedfile.txt`. That should tell you if it's a file or directory.
2. Test your configuration manually with plain docker using `-v` to mount the volumes, e.g.:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v /sourcedir/file.txt:/target/mountedfile.txt ubuntu:latest bash
```

Also, there may be some useful information in a (somewhat) [unrelated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71901906/5362795).