# Error mounting directory created in derived image with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

##### Summary

With *docker-compose*, mounting a volume with a destination directory that exists in the Nginx base image, works as expected. However, I get an error with `docker-compose up` when the mount target is a subdirectory created in the derived image. Here's the gist of the error:

> mounting "newdir" to rootfs at "/usr/share/nginx/html/newdir" caused:
> mkdir newdir: read-only file system: unknown

I don't understand why it seems to be attempting to create the directory (*newdir*) when it already exists!

##### Details

Full error below:

```
ERROR: for test_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/home/user/test/newdir" to rootfs at "/usr/share/nginx/html/newdir"  caused: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/accdaa147d7825a7d2c71b68f76e0b8663d00f6e46fcfb5c0ec32ada8baf85af/merged/usr/share/nginx/html/newdir: read-only file system: unknown

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:545: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:76: mounting "/home/user/test/newdir" to rootfs at "/usr/share/nginx/html/newdir" caused: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/accdaa147d7825a7d2c71b68f76e0b8663d00f6e46fcfb5c0ec32ada8baf85af/merged/usr/share/nginx/html/newdir: read-only file system: unknown.
```

Here is the *docker-compose.yml*:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: local/mynginx:withsubdir
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
      - ./newdir:/usr/share/nginx/html/newdir
```

The above image, `local/mynginx:withsubdir`, was built with the following *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM docker.io/library/nginx:1.21
RUN  mkdir /usr/share/nginx/html/newdir && ls -lah /usr/share/nginx/html/newdir
```

And I verified that I can mount the volume and see its content with docker:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti -v /home/user/test/newdir:/usr/share/nginx/html/newdir local/mynginx:withsubdir bash
root@7db709476271:/# ls /usr/share/nginx/html/newdir
hallo.imhere
```

So the issue seems specific to *docker-compose*. If I remove the last line in *docker-compose.yml* then `docker-compose up` starts successfully. How can I mount the directory created in the derived image? Thank you.

##### Extra Notes

By the way, my original *docker-compose.yml* is longer and it has a build step that points to the *Dockerfile* that creates that new directory. But I created this smaller reproducer while troubleshooting, and  I've built the new image manually with:

```
docker build . -t local/mynginx:withsubdir
```

I get the same error in two different environments (*Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu1~20.04.1* and *Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed5707e*), with or without `:ro`.

My `test` directory files:

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── html
│   └── index.html
└── newdir
    └── hallo.imhere
```

I did some online research but could not find any solution.

Comment: Does the directory `./html/newdir` exist on your host system?  (It can be empty, but does it exist at all?)

Comment: No, the host tree is as shown. The destination path does not have to exist in the host. If I leave only the second mount `./newdir:/usr/share/nginx/html/newdir` it works fine, the issue was the overlapping mounts, as explained in my answer.

Comment: the reason is, if your file does not exist docker creates it as a directory causing this weird error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Docker is trying to create the mount point in the read-only directory, and failing.

The normal Linux **mount**(8) call, and the underlying **mount**(2) system call, mount some filesystem on some existing directory.  A Linux bind mount is a special case of this where the filesystem that's being mounted is also an existing directory, and a Docker bind mount uses this same mechanism.

In general, in Docker, if the target of any kind of mount doesn't already exist, Docker will create it as a new empty directory.  Normally this is in the container filesystem, but if you're trying to mount a volume inside some other kind of mounted volume, the mount point will be created in the outer volume.

One easy way to demonstrate this is with a plain `docker run` command, where you mount an outer and an inner volume, but the outer volume is actually a bind mount:

```sh
# Create a new empty local "outer" directory
rm -rf outer
mkdir outer

# Create a new empty container...
docker run --rm \
  -v "$PWD/outer:/outer" \ # bind-mounting the outer directory
  -v inner:/outer/inner  \ # mounting a named volume within that
  busybox                \ # running any image
  ls /outer                # and a command that exits immediately

# Look inside the host directory, and an empty `inner` directory will exist
ls ./outer

# Clean up
docker volume rm inner
rm -rf outer
```

(This is the same mechanism as [Why does docker create empty node_modules and how to avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269442/why-does-docker-create-empty-node-modules-and-how-to-avoid-it).)

Now, with these mechanics in mind, you've told Docker to mount the outer directory as read-only, and it does.  Then the `newdir` directory doesn't exist in the container filesystem, so Docker tries to create it as the mount point, but it can't, because the directory is in a read-only filesystem.  That's the error you get.

With pure Docker volumes, some possible workarounds are to:

1. Create the mount point on your host filesystem before you start the container

   ```sh
   mkdir ./html/newdir
   docker-compose up -d
   ```
2. Don't mount the outer directory as read-only

   ```yaml
   volumes:
     - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html  # not ...:ro
   ```
3. Mount the inner directory somewhere else, as you've done in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71898649)

   ```yaml
   volumes:
     - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
     - ./newdir:/usr/share/nginx/newdir:ro  # not under .../html
   ```

A better answer still could be to avoid volumes here entirely.  In a Dockerfile you can `COPY` this content into your image.  Since the container filesystem is isolated from the host, this removes the risk of the container modifying the host files, and you can restructure the content however you want within the Dockerfile.  This also means you can run the image on another system without also having a copy of the files you want to serve there.

```sh
FROM nginx
COPY html/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
COPY newdir/ /usr/share/nginx/html/newdir/
# no need to repeat base image's EXPOSE or CMD
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! I like solution 2 the best. Using volumes instead of `COPY` was *intentional* in my case as it's more convenient during development, but it's a good point.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be the fact that the second destination mount is a subdirectory of the first. I changed my docker-compose.yml to this after building a new image and the error is now gone:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: local/mynginx:withsubdir
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro
      - ./newdir:/usr/share/nginx/newdir:ro
```

Hopefully that's something I can work with, but at least the mystery appears to be solved.